# Request.get() Access Denied - Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm struggling to try to access the data from a website I wish I could import some data from (I'm new to web scraping)

At the very beginning of the code I did some prints in order to check how it was going:

```
import requests

login_data={
   "login": "login"
   "pwd": "pwd"
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url_1 = "(website)"

    r=s.post(url_1, data=login_data)
    
    #when logging in, I am directed to the "(website/page2)"
    url_2 = "(website/page2)"
    r=s.get(url_2)

    print(r.text)
```

And, then, I got the following output:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>
 
You don't have permission to access "(website)" on this server.<P>
Reference...
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Is there any workaround on this access issue?

Thanks

Comment: how does the website validate your login? Do they use authorization header? Cookie?

Comment: Can you share the url of the site you are trying to login to? Some sites will require a CSRF token. You would need to inspect the site to get more information.

Comment: when logging in, the Network Tab of Inspect Page shows both set-cookies and www-authenticate information, but I'm not sure how it is authorized. The logging url is https://www.clear.com.br/pit/signin?controller=SignIn